How we can read last x days teams calls Data using API
I have application which read teams calls reacords using "callrecords" graphAPI. As all this happen realtime, when i stop my application for sometime calls data get loss. So, i want to read last x days teams calls.
I have to read teams last x days for all users in teams. Any API could you suggest?

Could you share which endpoint do you call? https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/callrecords-cloudcommunications-list-callrecords or https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/onlinemeeting-list-recordings ?
